# Correct/best words to describe "Training Day" and its common components

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests, military

I work in a clinic on a military base that closes for a half day once a month for something we call ***Training Day***. The two main parts of training day are (1) *Squadron **Commander's Call*** and (2) ***Flight Level Training***.

I am looking for alternative terms for: (a) *Training Day* as a whole; (1) *Commander's Call*, which happens in the auditorium; and (2) *Flight Level Training*, which happens in the classroom.  The terms should **not** be military specific, and they should convey the frequency, structure, size, purpose and content and value of the events and ways to add professional weight to them.

The words conference, convention, meeting, lecture, speech, lesson, presentation, briefing, seminar, workshop and training all come to mind, but they are not quite right.  Moreover, some of the things we usually label "briefings" seem more like "workshops" or "seminars"

(1) ***Squadron Commander's Call***: The squadron to which I belong (Laboratory, Radiology, Logistic and Records Personnel) meets in the clinic auditorium for between 30 minutes and 2 hours. Our Commander and/or First Sergeant speaks, there is a small promotion ceremony and recognition for squadron and/or individual achievements and mission objectives and upcoming events are reviewed.  There is usually a speech about one or more work related subjects. Occasionally there will be second speaker, who might be a guest, who talks on a topic that affects all squadrons, for example a mental health professional speaking about depression awareness. Sometimes the guest speaker has the squadron participate by answering questions or taking part in a short activity such as a safety skit

Examples of how I've used this term in a sentence include:

> Airman Smith was coined at Commanders call yesterday!
>
> Go ahead and check that patient in, they said patients shouldn't be
>   waiting for more than 10 minutes at the last commanders call.
>
> We learned about ways to manage stress during commander's call.

(2) ***Flight Level Training***:  The entire Laboratory team plus the flight commander and the flight chief meet in the conference room. There are power point presentations, a required safety brief, an infection control brief, and a presentation by a student on their research.  A department head may want to talk about changes in test procedure, a team member may present on a topic of their choice,  or our flight leadership may have been instructed to present on specific topic. Some of these are formal presentations with questions held to the end, and some are informal, with lively discussions. Presentations vary from several minutes to 30 minutes. At the end of the meeting, the flight chief presents a certificate to the "Student of the Month" and an "Employee of the Month".  We do not have one name for this part of training day but we've called it "small group discussions," "flight specific training," "flight level training," or even just "training day".

I am also looking for terms or words that will convey, in a resume or during an appraisal, that I am more knowledgeable in certain areas such as teamwork, or leadership than peers who do not attend training days. I am keeping a brief log of training and teamwork sessions.  Is it adequate to say: "I have participated in 12 teamwork lessons this year." Or should I be more specific and say: "I attended 12 lessons about many medical subjects, including Zika Virus, Diabetes, Cholesterol testing, Liver diseases and Alzheimer's disease." Or possibly, "I am able to properly respond to an infection control situation because I attended 12 Infection control trainings this year."

Comment: I think you should reduce this question to **just** what is relevant (we don't really need all the possible alternatives, only a broad outline of each event). Note that to split paragraphs up you need a completely empty line.

Comment: I am working on editing. I think I have removed approximately 1000 characters so far. This is difficult for me, as I am afraid that I won't get what I'm looking for if I am not detailed enough.

Comment: I think you are still going to get a lot of tl:dr on this. You spend a lot of time talking about flight level training, Comander´s Call, Training day, readiness training, briefings, group discussions, etc. and it is _still not clear_ what you need.

Comment: Should  OP try  - http://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Should I delete this temporarily until I can figure out a better way to express what I need? Maybe i just need to separate this into completely separate questions, Post them in the appropriate sections and try to keep track of it.

Comment: I took a stab at editing your question.  It is still too long.  If you don't like my edit, just roll back to your version.  I hope I haven't changed the meaning of anything, but you have so many terms specific to your organization and the military that I may have.  If so, apologies!  I recommend that you take out the last paragraph completely and ask it in a separate question on Workplace, as another commenter suggested.  And I do not understand why you want alternate, non-military terms.  Training Day seems fine to me.

Comment: Squadron Commander's Call sounds a lot like the All-Hands meetings in a place where I worked.  As for Flight Level Training, I am not sure what you mean by squadron, team, department, group, flight.  Flying in the dark, so to speak, I suggest Laboratory Group Training

Comment: Re your last paragraph:  The first sample sentence is vague.  The other two are good.

Comment: @ab2 Thank you for your help! Your edit is actually perfect! To answer your question, I am trying to refrain from military language because I am trying to begin a log/portfolio of all my professional and academic progress in preparation for the civilian world.

Comment: @ab2 So far, I like the terms All-Hands meetings and Laboratory group training. In the last paragraph, I think I am just struggling with choosing the most accurate word for the situation. Since the lab training itself contains multiple "types of learning" I have to make decide if the infection control is a training or a briefing, or if the research presentation can be considered a lesson, a lecture or something else. And then I have to decide what to call something that has all of these thing rolled into one. Thinking about it now, I could ask about that in a separate question.

Comment: I don't know if you still need these terms, but your *Squadron Commander's Call* sounds like an [*in-service*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-service_program) training program. I think the term would be pretty widely understood in several fields, including medicine and education.

Answer (score 2):

The key is to pull terminology from a non-military context.  I will make some suggestions to get you started, but then you can have some fun googling, looking at schedules for training sessions, conferences and workshops.

Monthly Staff Training

Professional Development Day

Opening Speaker

Breakout Session

Workshop Session

Also, google some sample CVs to get more ideas.

I think the documentation you're creating will look good on your CV.